# `\item[0.]\label{fst}` then `\ref{fst}` gives `1.2` rather than `0`; how do I label an `enumerate` block item properly?

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, labels

```tex
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[0.] \label{fst} Foo
  \item In \ref{fst} I said
\end{enumerate}
```

Want:

```
In 0 I said
```

Got:

```
In 1.2 I said
```

(happy to have extra full-stop; i.e., `0.`)

Comment: Could you turn this into a complete example?  I get "0. Foo" and "1. In  I said" (with two spaces between "in" and "I").  So you're doing something you've not shown us.

Comment: Double-checked, I'm in a `\subsection{}`, 1.2 subsection specifically, and that's what gets the 1.2 number from. So I guess the `\item` isn't `\label`led?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\item[...]` doesn't generate a number.

You can use `enumitem` and its `start` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start=0]
\item \label{zero} text
\item text
\end{enumerate}

Item~\ref{zero}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even start *all* your `enumerate` environments from 0.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{start=0}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{zero} text
\item text
\end{enumerate}

Item~\ref{zero}

\begin{enumerate}
\item another
\item test
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, the global setting is even better than what I was seeking.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, if you `[]` an item, then you remove its numbering for reference.  If you want the entire list to start at zero, then the simplest would be to adjust the counter so that's what it does:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}
  \item \label{fst} Foo
  \item In \ref{fst} I said
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

gives "In 0 I said" (I assume that you want 1 to come after 0).  If you want even more, I would encourage you to look into the `enumitem` package.  For example, `setlist[enumerate]{start=0}` would allow all of your enumerates to start at 0, not just this one, while the ref key would allow your reference to have the full-stop.

Comment: Thanks, the `\begin{enumerate}[start=1]` was required for nested enumerations so that might be a good note to add also.